# ReacNative: requireNativeComponent:"CKCameraManager" was not found in the UIManager

Tags: react-native, camera, qr-code

I want to open Camer by using the below npm package, but it is producing this error.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-camera-kit

```
import {CameraScreen} from 'react-native-camera-kit';
 <CameraScreen
          // Barcode props
          scanBarcode={true}
          onReadCode={(event) => Alert.alert('QR code found')} // optional
          showFrame={true} 
          laserColor="red" 
          frameColor="white" 
        />
```

[image]

Comment: That means the package you are using is not found in your current application build, which means either you forgot to re-build the app, or if you're using react-native < 0.60, you forgot to link the package. try `react-native run-android`, it should fix the error. Also, react-native-camera-kit has additional steps for android, do these if you haven't https://github.com/teslamotors/react-native-camera-kit/blob/master/docs/kotlin.md

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It's an issue with the import in the package itself. Go to `CameraScreen.tsx` file either by exploring the node modules folder manually or just `Ctrl + Left Click` on the class `CameraScreen` in your code. In there, scroll to top and look at the imports. There will be a red line (depends on your code editor) under the `Camera` import (as shown in the attached image). Just change it to `./Camera.android` or `./Camera.ios` depending on the platform you're developing for. Solved my issue.
[Image or problematic code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fo5Bb.png)